# HTML encode/escape with Rails with provide function

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, html-entities

I would like to have the title `Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Foo's` in my `new.html.erb` page. My layout is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>  
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", 
    "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="container">
        <%= yield %>
    </div>
</body>
```

my `new.html.erb` :

```
<% provide(:title, "Foo's") %>
<h1>Sign up</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/users/new.html.erb</p>
```

But my title is wrong :

[image]

How can I do it ?

--

Full_title

```
module ApplicationHelper

  # Returns the full title on a per-page basis.
  def full_title(page_title)
    base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
    if page_title.empty?
      base_title
    else
      "#{base_title} | #{page_title}"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What is `full_title`?

Comment: I have edited with the full_title

Comment: I have an encoding error ! Look the description

Comment: Now that you've edited the question this is clear. Previously you had a different desired title. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found :

just add `.html_safe` in my `full_title` function

module ApplicationHelper

```
  # Returns the full title on a per-page basis.
  def full_title(page_title)
    base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
    if page_title.empty?
      base_title
    else
      "#{base_title} | #{page_title}".html_safe
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this exact same thing and discovered a safer solution than using `html_safe`.

First, the method:

```
def full_title(page_title)
  base_title = "".html_safe
  base_title << "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  if page_title.present?
    base_title << " | "
    base_title << page_title
  end
  base_title
end
```

This escapes `page_title` if it is unsafe, but leaves it unescaped if it is safe.

This allows `"Foo's"` to display properly, but also escapes `"<script>alert('foo')</script>"` -- for instance, if some malicious user manages to enter custom text into a field that is displayed in a title tag, or if you ever accidentally use risky text yourself.

The explanation boils down to this -- `'foo'.html_safe` returns an ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer which acts like a String in every way except one: When you append a String to a SafeBuffer (by calling + or <<), that other String is HTML-escaped before it is appended to the SafeBuffer. When you append another SafeBuffer to a SafeBuffer, no escaping will occur. Rails is rendering all of your views under the hood using SafeBuffers, so the updated method above ends up providing Rails with a SafeBuffer that we've controlled to perform escaping on the `page_title` "as-needed" rather than "always".

Now, the credit for this answer goes entirely to Henning Koch, and is explained in far more detail at [Everything you know about html_safe is wrong](http://makandracards.com/makandra/2579-everything-you-know-about-html_safe-is-wrong) -- my recap above attempts only to provide the essence of the explanation in the event that this link ever dies.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a custom helper : `full_title`, that displays a base name followed by a `|` character then what you provide.

If you want only your title, you should do :

```
 <title><%= yield(:title) %></title>
```

Comment: I mean, I would like the full title but without the `&#39;`